# Compact operator maps and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

in my way to understand some spectral theorems I got stuck in the following property for compact operators.

If I got an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ which is compact, $(u_n) \in E$, and $u_n \rightharpoonup u$(weak convergence), then $<Tu_n, u_n> \to <Tu,u>$ strongly in $E$, where  E is a hilbert space.

**What I know:**

Since $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $T$ is compact then $|| Tu_n - Tu|| \rightarrow 0$ strongly in $E$. And with this I should be able to work a good bound for $|<Tu_n, u_n> - <Tu,u>|$ as we do for all typical properties of continuity and stuff like that, but I haven't been able to do that.

I'd be really glad you guys could help me out, thanks so much in advance. :)

Comment: What does $\langle Tu , u \rangle $ mean?

Comment: Is $F$ a Hilbert space?

Comment: I agree with @KaboMurphy. The inner product is defined as a binary operation on a single space. The notation $\langle Tu,u\rangle$ does not make sense because $Tu\in F$ while $u\in E$.

Comment: The inner product sir. Basically what the proposition is saying that the convergence is conserved by the inner product(I think).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467415/compact-operators-and-inner-product-of-weakly-convergent-sequences

Comment: Even if $E=F$  and the space is a Hilbert space the term 'strong convergence in $F$' for the  inner product does not make sense.

Comment: I edited, sorry. E is a Hilbert Space now

Comment: $u$ is in $E$ and $Tu$ in $F$, so $\langle Tu, u \rangle$ has no meaning.

Comment: @KaboMurphy the question has been edited, now $T$ is a linear endomorphism on $E$.

Comment: Im really sorry, I misspelled everything. Now should be ok. Sorry for the trouble guys <3

Comment: $|<Tu_n, u_n> - <Tu,u>|=|<T(u_n-u), u_n>+ <Tu,u_n - u>|\leq||T(u_n-u)||\,||u_n||+|<Tu,u_n - u>|.$ Weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\langle Tu_n , u_n \rangle -\langle Tu , u \rangle|\leq  |\langle Tu_n , u_n \rangle -\langle Tu , u_n \rangle| +\langle Tu , (u_n-u) \rangle|$$  $$\leq \|Tu_n-Tu\| \|u_n\|+|\langle Tu , (u_n-u) \rangle|.$$ Note that weak convergence implies boundedness of $(u_n)$.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your answer. The expression $+|\langle Tu,(u_n-u)\rangle|$ appears in the middle of a sentence, which does not make sense.